# Liquibase unable to pass changeLogParameters

Tags: mysql, gradle, groovy, liquibase

I am using liquibase-gradle-plugin and Groovy DSL to apply the changesets in my database. I have made necessary configurations in the gradle scripts as per the [documentation](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin) of the plugin. There is also a [relevant issue](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin/issues/9) which has been marked as `Closed` and seems to be working for other users. However, the properties are not resolving in my SQL file. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Contents of `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.2.4"
        classpath group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.liquibase.gradle'
liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile "${project.projectDir}/src/main/db/changelogs.groovy"
            changeLogParameters([
                    name    : 'foo',
                    category: 'bar'
            ])
            url "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true"
            username 'test'
            password 'test'
            driver 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
        }
    }
}
```

Contents of `changelogs.groovy`

```
databaseChangeLog(logicalFilePath: '/db/changelogs.groovy') {

    changeSet(id: '1', author: 'abc', runAlways: true) {

        comment 'Init.'
        sqlFile(path: 'scripts/init.sql', relativeToChangelogFile: true)

    }
}
```

Contents of `init.sql`

```
USE TEST;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MY_TABLE;

CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(
    NAME VARCHAR(100),
    CATEGORY VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('${name}', '${category}');

COMMIT;
```

SQL Output:

```
mysql-sql> select * from  my_table;
+---------+-------------+
| NAME    | CATEGORY    |
+---------+-------------+
| ${name} | ${category} |
+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here I would have expected the table to contain 'foo' and 'bar' for name and category respectively.

The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/srikanthanusuri/liquibase-example).

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you need to replace this line:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('${name}', '${category}');
```

with this:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ("${name}", "${category}");
```

The difference is that the first line uses single quotes which translate to literal strings. The second line use double quotes, which allows for String interpolation (a.k.a. String templates).

Here is a quote from http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html

> Also note the difference between single quotes and double quotes in
>   Groovy: single quotes always create Java Strings, without
>   interpolation of variables, whereas double quotes either create Java
>   Strings or GStrings when interpolated variables are present.

Read more about single quoted, double quoted and triple quoted Strings here: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings

Comment: I tried that and does not seem to work. The output seems to be the same.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the parameters are not being passed into the `changelogs.groovy` file since when I try printing out the values, the update simply fails.

Execution failed for task ':update'.
> liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Unexpected error running Liquibase: No such property: name for class: org.liquibase.groovy.delegate.ChangeSetDelegate

Comment: How about this? `INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ("'${name}'", "'${category}'");`

Comment: Or the other way around: `INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('"${name}"', '"${category}"');`

Comment: I have created a repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/srikanthanusuri/liquibase-example) with the above code. Would you be able to verify if your changes are working?

Comment: If php or perl is under the covers, it needs to be `"'$...'"`.  But that begs for "sql injection" by a hacker.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug in the newer versions. I am able to pass in the params to the changelog file using version `1.1.1` as specified [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.liquibase.gradle/1.1.1), however, this is still not getting into the SQL file.